# How do I change svg icon color in qt designer?

Tags: python, c++, qt-designer

[Icons are not looking good here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txlHe.png)

need to change the icons to white so that they look good. I want to do this inside of qt-designer instead of modifying the xml files by opening and closing over and over again.

i tried svg{color:#color} property in the button, but i couldnt seem to target the icon itself.

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by "not good" and what you would consider looking good. Nor do I know how you created your icons and how you tried to add the css and what happened when you did. A [mcve] would help.